# polymorphic .find_or_create_by with mongoid 2.0.1, on embedded document collections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, polymorphism, mongoid

in previous released of Mongoid (2.0.beta.20), I could pass a class type as the
2nd parameter of the .find_or_create_by block on embedded document collections.
this doesn't appear to be the case any more, with v2.0.1, yet I still
need to do polymorphic find_or_create_by. any suggestions / pointers
on how to do this?

I used to do this:

`SomeClass.childclass.find_or_create_by({:key => "value"},
InheritingChildClass)`

now I get an exception saying too many arguments (2 for 1)
on .find_or_create_by.

how can I tell the collection to create an object of the correct type, when using find_or_create_by? Or, how can i create my own method that will be functionaly equivalent to what I want, and be re-usable across my embedded document collections?

any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own solution for this

```
module Mongoid::Relations
  class Many
    def find_or_new(attrs, type, &block)
      inst = self.where(attrs).first

      unless inst
        inst = type.new
        inst.write_attributes attrs
        self << inst
      end

      inst
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understood your need to inform the subclass, but check this gist: https://gist.github.com/960684

I do search subclass instances without needing to inform it. Perhaps your scenario really needs it, but if it does, why don't you call subclass's find_or_create_by?

Comment: hmmm, now I do understand '- - .. if you want something like Person.find_or_create_by to generate a subclass instance, this could be a problem.

Comment: yes. also - i can't seem to call InheritingChildClass.find_or_create_by. it throws exceptions saying i can't access the class directly and have to use the collection.